# Join continued lines together

Tags: bash, shell

I have data similar to this

```
prop1: val
prop2: val
 val continued
 continued still
prop3: val
```

I want to turn it into

```
prop1: val
prop2: val val continued continued still
prop3: val
```

so that it is easier to filter the props I want. I can't think of a simple way to do this.

Any suggestions? using awk/sed/tr/whatever.

Comment: Thanks for the correction CharlesB :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n/1252191#1252191) to a related question showed me the way. In short:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n / /g' file.txt
```

Or if you're on BSD or OS X:

```
sed -e ':a' -e 'N' -e '$!ba' -e 's/\n / /g' file.txt
```

Click through on the link for a fairly thorough explanation of how this works.

Comment: Yes, this is just what I wanted. Works like a charm. Thanks Jordan.

Answer (score 0):

`formail -c` does this if your input looks like email headers throughout.

Comment: Yes, they are indeed email headers. Also, I don't have the `formail` command. While I can find out and install it, I'd prefer a solution without external dependencies.